# Javascript : Interchange X and Y value in nested list

Tags: javascript, list

Let's say i have the following list in Json and i wish to interchange every value (X,Y) to (Y,X)

```
[
    [
        [
            99.624023,
            6.249776
        ],
        [
            100.17334,
            5.790897
        ],
        [
            100.50293,
            3.754634
        ],
        [
            100.876465,
            2.833317
        ],
        [
            99.624023,
            6.249776
        ]
    ]
]
```

Can i ask any simple and better method to solve this case?

Comment: what means more simple or better? please add your code.

Comment: Did you tried anything so far ?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: `coord[0].forEach(arr => [arr[0], arr[1]] = [arr[1], arr[0]]);`

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan. And i am looking for optimizing, currently i am using splice method. Looks weird

Comment: What optimisation do you expect from the code I posted?

Comment: Try to make less operation done in JS. Make code structure as easy as possible.
I just do like 
`coord[0].forEach(arr => [arr[1], arr[0]]);`